# Ruby 1.9 Rails 3 Start Daemon with Variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I have a Daemon I am trying to start but I would like to set a few variables in the daemon when starting it. Here is the script I am using to control my daemons locates in RAILSAPP/script/daemon

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

ENV["APP_ROOT"] ||= File.expand_path("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/..")
ENV["RAILS_ENV_PATH"] ||= "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/config/environment.rb"

script = "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/daemons/#{ARGV[1]}"

Daemons.run(script, dir_mode: :normal, dir: "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/tmp/pids")
```

When I start this daemon I would like to pass a variable to it like a reference to an active record so I can base the daemon's initial run off of it.

Comment: I suppose that your reference will come from another ruby process. If so maybe you can pass it via http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html (i haven't tested it though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch a specific ActiveRecord object, you can either pass just the id, or the classname + id as an additional parameter on the commandline. As you're already using ARGV[1] for the script name, you could pass it as ARGV[2] and something like Product_123 that you then parse via split, and do a Product.find(123) to get the actual record.

Another approach would be to put the object information into a queue like memcached or redis, and have the daemon fetch the information out of the queue. That would keep your daemon startup a bit simpler, and would allow you to queue up multiple records for the daemon to process. (Something just processing a single record would probably be better written as a script anyway.)

The other concern I have about your script is using ENV["APP_ROOT"]. Does that really need to go in the environment? What if you have a second daemon? It seems that it would be better as a local variable, and if you need it in the daemon, you can always get it relative to where the daemon's file is located anyway.